# tkinter Button with time pressed dependent action

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

I need some help to create a code in Tkinter that will output differnet values as a specific button is held down longer. So for example if button a is held down for one second it will output 1, or held down for 5 seconds it outputs 5, and so on.

```py
def set_down():
    acl.bind('<Button-1>',gn)
    brk.bind('<Button-1>',gn)


    # set function to be called when released
def set_up():
    acl.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',fn)
    brk.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',fn)


def fn(fn):
    print(0,'up')
def gn(gn):
    print(1,'down')

# the actual buttons: 

img = PhotoImage(file='round.gif')
brk_img = PhotoImage(file = 'red.gif')
acl = Button(GUI_CONTROL, text = 'accelerate', command = lambda:[set_down(), set_up()], image = img, padx = 4, pady = 4,
                bg = 'cyan', fg = 'cyan')
acl.place(relx = 0.7, rely = 0.5)

brk = Button(GUI_CONTROL, text = 'break', image = brk_img, command = lambda:[set_down(), set_up()],  padx=4,pady=4)

brk.place(relx = 0.7, rely=0.7)
```

So I already have the function to output to the user whether it is being held down or not, but now I just need it to change the number value on the print function for fn() and gn() if it's pressed down for longer or not.

Comment: Add from time import time, and then in your callbacks record the time between them. I.e. start = time() once you press the button and end = time() once you release it. The time interval is then end-start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass `tk.Button` to create a `TimePressedButton` that takes an action depending on the duration it was pressed:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time


class TimePressedButton(tk.Button):
    """A tkinter Button whose action depends on the
    duration it was pressed
    """

    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.start, self.end = 0, 0
        self.set_down()
        self.set_up()
        self['text'] = 'press me'
        self['command'] = self._no_op

    def _no_op(self):
        """keep the tk.Button default pressed/not pressed behavior
        """
        pass

    def set_down(self):
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.start_time)

    def set_up(self):
        self.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.end_time)

    def start_time(self, e):
        self.start = time.time()

    def end_time(self, e):
        if self.start is not None:  # prevents a possible first click to take focus to generate an improbable time
            self.end = time.time()
            self.action()
        else:
            self.start = 0

    def action(self):
        """defines an action that varies with the duration
        the button was pressed
        """
        print(f'the button was pressed for {self.end - self.start} seconds')
        self.start, self.end = 0, 0


root = tk.Tk()
btn = TimePressedButton(root)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```